# The method orElseThrow(() -> {}) is undefined for the type Page<Categories>

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

This is the service implementation class of a small project. where I got some errors on the lambda function. first I wrote Lambda function without error but at that time the variable "cId in String datatype" then I changed to "Long".

The code is described below. where the error is

```
The method orElseThrow(() -> {}) is undefined for the type Page<Categories>
```

first of all thanks and regards. 
And kindly please help me to fix the error.

```
package com.snipe.giftplanner.services;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.snipe.giftplanner.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.snipe.giftplanner.model.Categories;
import com.snipe.giftplanner.repository.CategoriesRepository;

@Service
@Transactional
public class CategoriesServicesImpl {

@Autowired
private CategoriesRepository crepo;

public Categories createCategory(Categories category) {
    return crepo.save(category);
}
public Page<Categories> getAllCategory(Pageable pageable) {
    return crepo.findAll(pageable);
}
public ResponseEntity<?> getCategory(Long cId) {
    return crepo.findById(cId).map(category -> { 
        crepo.getOne(cId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("cId " + cId + " not found"));   
}
public ResponseEntity<?> deleteCategory(Long cId) {
    return crepo.findById(cId).map(category -> {
        crepo.delete(category);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("cId " + cId + " not found"));
}
public Categories updateCategory(Long cId,Categories categoryRequest) {
    return crepo.findById(cId).map(category -> {
        category.setCname(categoryRequest.getCname());
        category.setDescription(categoryRequest.getDescription());
        return crepo.save(category);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("CID " + cId + " not found"));
}
public void deleteAllCategory() {
     crepo.deleteAll();      
}   
public Categories findByCname(String cname) {
    Categories obj = crepo.findByCname(cname);
    return obj; 
}
}
```

Comment: is `findById` supposed to return an `Optional`?

Comment: Which line give this error?

Comment: '.orElseThrow' shows the error

Comment: As @Eran said in my case i expected the underlying class to be an optional but used the wrong dependency version where it wasnt an optional